# Residence permit for visitor visa in uk

Tags: uk, residency

I am Italian permit card holder. My parents are Italian citizenship holder. And right now my father is living and working in UK. My mother and sister will be joining him within few days. Being a self depended and over 21 yrs old, I can't apply for EEA Family visa. Now I want to ask you If I get UK Visitor visa and visit my family in the UK, Afterthat is there any chance to get residence permit from that visitor visa?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can certainly apply for a Visitor Visa. But if you get one, no way can you change it into a permission to remain. You need a different process altogether and that would be better asked on expatriates.stackexchange.com.